# Detect presence of a specific pattern in Javascript String

Tags: javascript, regex, string, indexof

How can i do to search if a Javascript String contains the following pattern :

"@aRandomString.temp"

I would like to know if the String contains @ character and then any String and then ".temp" string.

Thanks

Comment: A pattern with a "random string" is not a "specific string" :-) You might fix your title…

Answer (score 1):

This one liner should do the job using [`regex#test(Strng)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```
var s = 'foo bar @aRandomString.temp baz';
found = /@.*?\.temp/i.test(s); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `indexOf` to find a string within a string.

```
var string = "@aRandomString.temp";
var apos = string.indexOf("@");
var dtemp = string.indexOf(".temp", apos); // apos as offset, invalid: ".temp @"
if (apos !== -1 && dtemp !== -1) {
    var aRandomString = string.substr(apos + 1, dtemp - apos);
    console.log(aRandomString); // "aRandomString"
}
```

Comment: I don't understand (+1), but your solution is a bit complicated :-) Also OP only wants to know whether the match exists, not what the random string is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the match function.
match expects the regular expression.

```
function myFunction()
{
    var str="@someting.temp"; 
    var n=str.test(/@[a-zA-Z]+\.temp/g);
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/IBACAB/1

Comment: What about the `.temp` part? Also, use `test` instead of `match`.

Comment: I have it in the regexp: (/@[a-zA-Z]+\.temp

Comment: @Bergi I am assuming that string only contains letters

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var str = "@something.temp";

if (str.match("^@") && str.match(".temp$")) {

}
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nf9GF/)**

Comment: The question asks for "contains", not for "is". Also, forgot to escape your regex, and you should use `test` instead of `match`