# Find a pattern into a string

Tags: javascript, string, split

I want to find a pattern into a string input.

Example:

String > Can I have the Outstanding amount for MEXB18342700?

Output > VAR = MEXB18342700.

How can I do it?

The pattern would be a word with three uppercase letter like MEX.

Comment: looks like you want a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Yup, something like `/([A-Z]{3}\d{8})/`

Comment: Duplicate: [Detect presence of a specific pattern in Javascript String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141403/detect-presence-of-a-specific-pattern-in-javascript-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Regular expression. Something like this:

```js
function getCode(sentence) {
    return sentence.match(/([A-Z]){3}\w+/g);
}

getCode('Can I have the Outstanding amount for MEXB18342700?'); // returns ['MEXB18342700']
getCode('Something else...') // null
```